# Having trouble with my GUI Program

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm really new to java and I am trying to create a GUI for my console application. I have the code written just need help fixing these errors. The program seems to run fine up until i enter the information in and the BMI read infinite and it scews all the data.If anyone is able to help me clean up my code to get it working it would help me out a lot because I am having aton of trouble with this.

Here is the codes for each class:

Health Profile Class

```
public class HealthProfile
{
    // attributes 

    private String name;

    private short age;
    private float weight; 
    private float height; //measured in total inches

    //constructors
    public HealthProfile() 
    {
        name = "unknown";
        age = 0;
        weight = 0.0f;
        height = 0.0f;
    }

    public HealthProfile(String name, short age, float weight, float height) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.height = height;
    }

    //behaviors 
    public float getBMI()
    {
        return (float) ((weight *703) / Math.pow(height, 2.0f));
    }
    public String getCategory()
    {
        float bmi = getBMI();
        if(bmi < 18.5f )
            return "Underweight";
        else if( bmi >= 18.5f && bmi < 25)
            return "Normal";
        else if (bmi >= 25 && bmi < 30)
            return "Overweight";
        else 
            return "Obese";
    }
    public float getMaxHR()
    {
        return 220 - age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public short getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int i) {
        if ( i > 0 && i < 150)
            this.age = (short) i;
        else
            this.age = 0;
    }

    public float getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(double d) {
        if (d > 0.0f && d <1000.0f)
            this.weight = (float) d;
        else
            this.weight = 0.0f;
    }

    public float getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(float height_feet, float height_inches) {
        this.height = (height_feet *12) + height_inches;
    }
}
```

GUI Class:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class HealthProfileGUI extends JFrame
{
    //Create GUI components
    private JTextField txtName, txtAge, txtWeight, txtHeightFt, txtHeightIn, 
    txtBMI, txtCategory, txtMxHeartRate; 
    private JButton btnDisplay, btnClear;
    private HealthProfile hthPro;

    //Constructor for  building the GUI
    public HealthProfileGUI()
    {
        //Add a name to the GUI
        super("Health Profile");
        hthPro = new HealthProfile();
        //instantiate components
        txtName = new JTextField (20);
        txtAge = new JTextField(10);
        txtWeight = new JTextField(10);
        txtHeightFt = new JTextField(10);
        txtHeightIn = new JTextField(10);
        btnDisplay = new JButton ("Display");
        btnClear = new JButton ("Clear");
        txtBMI = new JTextField(10);
        txtCategory = new JTextField(10);
        txtMxHeartRate = new JTextField(10);

        //set layout
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2)) ;
        //Add components to frame
        add(new JLabel("Name"));
        add(txtName);
        add(new JLabel("Age"));
        add(txtAge);
        add(new JLabel("Weight"));
        add(txtWeight);
        add(new JLabel("Height-Feet"));
        add(txtHeightFt);
        add(new JLabel("Height-Inches"));
        add(txtHeightIn);
        add(btnDisplay);
        add(btnClear);
        add(new JLabel("BMI"));
        add(txtBMI);
        add(new JLabel ("Category"));
        add(txtCategory);
        add(new JLabel ("Max Heart Rate"));
        add(txtMxHeartRate); 

        //set up event handlers
        //create an object
        ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();
        //connect the buttons to the ActionListener using this object
        btnDisplay.addActionListener(handler);
        btnClear.addActionListener(handler);        
    }//end constructor

    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    { //Start class
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //code to process the button events goes here
            if (e.getSource() == btnDisplay)
            {
                //VERIFY that user has provided all input
                if (txtName.getText().isEmpty() || 
                    txtAge.getText().isEmpty() || 
                    txtWeight.getText().isEmpty() ||
                    txtHeightFt.getText().isEmpty()||
                    txtHeightIn.getText().isEmpty()
                )//missing input
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please provide all input");
                    return;  //exit this method so user can correct
                }
                {
                    hthPro.setName(txtName.getText());
                    try
                    {
                        hthPro.setAge(Integer.parseInt(txtAge.getText()));
                        hthPro.setWeight(Double.parseDouble(txtWeight.getText()));
                        //hthPro.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(txtHeightFt.getText()));

                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException ex)
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hours, rate must be numeric");
                    }
                    txtBMI.setText(String.valueOf(hthPro.getBMI()));
                    txtCategory.setText(String.valueOf(hthPro.getCategory()));
                    txtMxHeartRate.setText(String.valueOf(hthPro.getMaxHR()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Lab2Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HealthProfileGUI frame = new HealthProfileGUI();
        frame.setSize(400, 300);  //these numbers are in pixels
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Thank you again for anyone that can help me i hope the problem isn't that big.

Comment: So what did you find when you stepped through your code with a debugger?

Comment: I would assume the problem is that you commented out the line calling `setHeight`, but you divide by `height` squared in your `getBMI` method. Division by 0 returns infinity.

Comment: 1) *"just need help fixing these errors"* What errors? Be specific and don't assume the reader can guess what they are. (As an aside, the code seems to run here without throwing errors.) 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). In this case, the code is probably short enough, but it should be a single 'copy/paste' compile & run, as opposed to 3 copy/pastes. That can be done by copying the `main` method into the `HealthProfileGUI` class, then demoting the `HealthProfile` to default (from `public`) & pasting it in @ end of same.

Answer (score 0):

BMI is infinite because the result of division by `Math.pow(0, 2.0f)`, uncomment your `setHeight` line:

```
hthPro.setHeight(Float.parseFloat(txtHeightFt.getText()),
            Float.parseFloat(txtHeightIn.getText()));
```

Then let's see your next problem.